# Chamar procedure dinamicamente

Tags: pl-sql

Alguém conhece um método para chamar uma procedure dinamicamente?

Estou criando uma tela html/css/javascript em uma procedure oracle.
Criei uma tabela com o nome das procedures que quero chamar.
Dessa forma quando houver uma nova funcionalidade no sistema, não preciso alterar o código principal só adicionar o nome da procedure na tabela.

Mais ou menos dessa forma

```
for c_dados in (select * from tabela where flag = 'S') loop

        htp.p('<div class="brick large" id="'||c_dados.id||'">');
      exxecute immediate 'begin'|| c_dados.nome_proc||'; end;';
         htp.p('</div> ');

     end loop;
```

Porém o execute immediate não funciona.
Alguém sabe de alguma outra forma?

Answer (score 1):

besteira minha faltava um espaço depois do begin

`execute immediate 'begin '|| c_dados.nome_proc||'; end;';`

Comment: Por favor, aceite sua pergunta como correta.